# how to convert arraylist to string array with all items in double quote

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, arrays

In my application i m getting a problem..
i am getting data from server into ArrayList. but i am unable to convert that list in to a String array in which all data items are in double quoted.

my code for getting arrayList is

```
public ArrayList<String> dataarea1(){   

        ArrayList<String>dataarea1=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
        Statement smt=mycon.connection().createStatement();
        rs=smt.executeQuery("DCRAREADDL "+ paid +",'','','',''");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            dataarea1.add(rs.getString("AREA"));
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataarea1;
    }
```

now i want to convert my ArrayList dataarea1 to a StringArray like this..

```
String[] colours = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange", "Purple" };
```

i want to convert my arraylist in this form but now it is converting in single quoted only....
if some one can tell me how to convert arraylist in Stringarray with all data item in double qoute

now i m using this code fro getting string array

```
public String GetName()
     {
         String colour = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dataarea3.size(); i++) {
                colour += ""+ dataarea3.get(i).toString() +"'"+ ",";

            }
            return colour;
     }
```

but here all items are placed in single quote........how i can put them in double quote

Comment: why can't you use arraylist in your application?

Comment: What do you mean by data item in double quote ? For showing them on the display ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the quotes characters ?

Comment: why do you want double quotes??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified function.You can use backslash("\") to put quotes.

public String GetName() {

```
     String colour = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < dataarea3.size(); i++) {
            colour += "\""+ dataarea3.get(i).toString() +"\"" + ",";

        }
        return colour;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code to convert the `ArrayList` to String array

```
public void ConvertArrayListToarray()
        {
            ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
            myArrayList.Add("Jhon");
            myArrayList.Add("Jill");
            myArrayList.Add("Jo");
            myArrayList.Add("Chris");

            String[] myArray = (String[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(string));
            string str = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
                           str += myArray[i] + "\n";
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String>  dataarea1= new ArrayList<String>();
dataarea1.add("ann");
dataarea1.add("john");
String[] mStringArray = new String[dataarea1.size()];
mStringArray = dataarea1.toArray(mStringArray);

for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
    Log.d("string is",(mStringArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [guava Iterables.toArray](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray%28java.lang.Iterable,java.lang.Class%29) it's simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join or escape double quote

```
"\""
```

Also, don't use += on strings, use StringBuilder/StringBuffer for concatenating a lot of strings

Answer (score 0):

If you need alle Strings in " just add \" in front of and an the end of each String.

```
static String[] convertToArray(List<String> list){
    String[] output = new String[list.size()];

    StringBuilder builder;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("\"");
        builder.append(list.get(i));
        builder.append("\"");
        output[i] = builder.toString();
    }

    return output;
}
```